# Renormalization conditions for massless phi-fourth theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

This questions concerns section 12.2, page 408 of Peskin and Schroeder's quantum field theory book. Among renormalization conditions listed in Eq. 12.30, the first one requires that self-energy correction for the scalar field be equal to zero at $p^2=-M^2$, where $M$ is the renormalization point. But should it not require instead that the self-energy correction be equal to zero at $p^2=0$, rather than at some unphysical point? Is this not the definition of masslessness? Moreover, in the rest of the section the authors act as if they used this latter definition and not the one dispayed in Eq. 12.30. So I am a little bit confused. Have the authors made a mistake?

Comment: Can you give an example of where the authors act as if they used the latter definition?

Comment: On page 409, when they describe subtraction, they say that the mass counterterm simply subtracts the quadratic divergence and after that one can forget about it. As a result, the remaining self-energy  correction  is just proportional to the momentum squared. But if one applies their renormalization condition, this is not true. The mass counterterm in this case depends on M^2 and, overall, the self-energy is not proportional to p^2, but also contains a term proportional to M^2.

Comment: I finally got around to reading this chapter and I feel like half of it is wrong. I think Peskin mixes up 'zero bare mass' and 'zero physical mass' several times as well as conflating Wilsonian and continuum RG. At the very least, he's not doing the same thing as the modern treatment found in newer books. Hopefully somebody else can shine some more light on this...

Comment: This was my impression too. Some of the sentences I just do not understand. For instance, on page 407: _In Wilson's language, 
a renormalized field theory with the cutoff taken arbitrarily large corresponds to a trajectory that takes an arbitrarily long time to evolve to a large value of the mass parameter._

Comment: On page 407 (in my copy) they say that "we assume for simplicity that the mass term m² has been adjusted to zero, so the theory sits just at its critical point." Surely this corresponds to a particular value of M for a given nonzero bare mass m0. But then it seems like they assume m = 0 for all M (at least M close to the fixed point). You could make it work if you pretend m0 depends on M, but that would invalidate the Callan-Symanzik equation. Maybe they are implicitly saying that the RG flow doesn't affect m² if m² is already 0, as seems to be indicated by Fig 12.1. Not sure if or why though.

Comment: In any case, if both m0 and m are zero, then the mass counterterm δm = Z⁻¹ m0 - m must also be zero and so can't cancel any divergences, but on page 412 (in my edition) they say "in massless ϕ⁴ theory, the one-loop propagator correction is completely canceled by the mass counterterm".